# Why width of flex container with max-content has different width than flex item?

Tags: css, flexbox, intrinsic-content-size

I want to understand why the parent flex container with width specified as "*max-content*" has different width than the lone inflexible child flex item.

As per my understanding of Flexbox [intrinsic size specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#intrinsic-item-contributions), the child has correct width, but the parent is not honouring the main-size max-content contribution of child.

Here is the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/c0f5xwn0/

```
<div style="width:max-content; display:flex;border:1px green solid;">
    <div style="height:100px; flex:0 0 100px; border:1px red solid; width:200px">Why parent div has more width than child?</div>
</div>
```

Can someone please explain the reason behind this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At the present time, the `max-content` value has weak support among major browsers.

Currently:

- it is not supported by Edge
- it has lots of issues in Firefox
- it has some issues in Chrome and Safari

See here for the complete picture: https://caniuse.com/#search=max-content

Assuming you are testing in Chrome, the main problem is your use of the `flex-basis` property. The flex item has:

```
flex: 0 0 100px /* fg: 0, fs: 0, fb: 100px */
```

According to the documentation linked to above, `max-content` does not recognize `flex-basis` in Chrome. Therefore, use `width` instead:

```html
<div style="width:max-content;display:flex;border: 1px green solid;">
    <div style="height:100px;width: 100px;border: 1px red solid;">Why parent div has more width than child?
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes that is what I thought that it would a bug in current implementation of Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

The width of the child div is being declared as `200px`. The content inside the child div is being clamped to `flex:0 0 100px`. The parent div adjusts for the `width:200px` attribute. By changing `width` to `100px` the parent div is now the same size.

Comment: This is the answer. The third property when you use `flex` is the width of the element which you have specified as `100px`. But it also has a width of 200px which the parent sees. Remove the flex property on the child and you will see the parent and the child have the same width.